# Scroll bar defaulted in the middle of a dialog box with long text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Hello I use Jquery UI dialog box to put in some long text.
Once I open the dialog box, it shows like this in default (It should show the upper part of the dialog box):
 [image]

I try to change the `$('.ui-dialog').css("top", "0px");`to push the scroll bar to the top, but it is not working. Is there anyway I can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: scrollTop()-based suggestions should work, but in the end they are compensating for something that I don't believe you should need compensating for. I would be inclined to inspect the CSS to see if some sort of style is causing the scrollbar to appear there, before solving with JS.

Comment: Good thoughts! Do you think it would relate to the current mouse position in a page?

Comment: If it's actually a JS problem, could be! If it's pure CSS, then no. If at all possible, it would be useful to see the live page.

Comment: Since the dialog is dynamically generated by jQuery UI it's unlikely that it's a CSS issue. As @gregp points out, it's pretty difficult to say any more without seeing a live demonstration of the issue.

Comment: CSS affect elements that are dynamically created as long as a selector matches. That's what I'm getting at-- after the widget is created, it contains something matching an existing style (top:50% being set somewhere; who knows!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.ui-dialog').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it is a very good way to go. Sorry for the late reply to this question.